# ElasticSearch Nested Filter Not Matching Emails

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm on ElasticSearch 1.0.1, using NEST and straight HTTP to query/test.

I have a doc like so:

```
 {      "_index": "orders_staging",
        "_type": "order",
        "_id": "1721",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "dbId": 1721,
           "id": "a0f4012b0351",
           "sourceId": "__micah",
           "partnerId": 7,
           "partnerName": "__Test34",
           "paymentMethodId": 1,
           "shippingAddress": {
              "addressId": 1553,
              "firstName": "Micah",
              "lastName": "Smith",
              "line1": "",
              "line2": "",
              "city": "Pittsburgh",
              "state": "PA",
              "countryCode": "US",
              "postalCode": "15201",
              "phone": "5551212",
              "email": "micah@me.com"
           },
           "dateCreated": "2012-10-24T15:11:10.193"
        }
}
```

When i run the following filter:

```
GET orders_staging/order/_search
{
 "from": 0,
 "size": 25,
 "filter": {
  "or":{
      "filters": [
         {
             "nested": {
                "path": "shippingAddress",
                "query": {
                    "term":{
                        "shippingAddress.email":{
                         "value":"micah"   
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
         }
      ]


 }
 }
}
```

It works, but if i use the full email `micah@me.com` it fails.

It seems like anything with an `@` symbol fails.

Any ideas? Is it impossible to `Term` match an Email? I've tried escaping it but with no luck (and its a POST anyways).

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason for this is that your email address might be tokenized during indexing. So instead of micah@me.com there are three tokens (terms): micah, me, com. If that is the case, try to add `"index": "not_analyzed"` to its mapping definition.

Comment: any links/tips on dynamically updating an existing mapping? extra thanks!

Comment: According to the ES documentation, you cannot change mapping for the field that already exists: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#updating-a-mapping (in that case, the only way is to drop index, update mapping and to reindex again). You can, however, add a new field to your index, under a different name, which has the same source (email address), but is indexed with `not_analyzed` specifier. You will still need to reindex though.

Comment: You can index to a new type/mapping, drop the old mapping (downtime of seconds), and add an alias to point the old type's name to the new mapping. 

Once you have an alias set up, you won't have to worry about the brief downtime.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the UAX Email URL Tokenizer. From the documentation:

> **UAX Email URL Tokenizer**
>
> A tokenizer of type uax_url_email which works exactly like the
>   standard tokenizer, but tokenizes emails and urls as single tokens.

It tokenizes the email address as a single token, facility email address searches.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html

Here is a decent example of appropriate index settings and mappings along with a link to sample code on Github:

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "index": {
      "analysis" :{
        "analyzer": {
           "default": {
             "type" : "custom",
             "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
             "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "stop"]
                       }
                    }
                  }
              }
       }
}
```

https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-test-scripts/blob/master/email_default_analyzer.sh

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a mapping? if so, is the shippingaddres.email a String or text field? if it's text, my guess is that the field might be getting tokenized. Try mapping the field as a string field if you are going to always match exact addresses

Comment: i checked and its a string. you can't exact match a string?

Comment: I thing you should be able to. try adding this to the mapping
 {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "norms" : {
                    "enabled" : false
                } 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

Comment: Additionally, if there's a reason for you to have both the analyzed and non-analyzed version, you can change it to a multi-field type: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html